# check if value is numeric in sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong with my case statement below?

If the value is numeric then I want to check if its greater than or equal to 5 and return 1 if true else return 0. Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Below CASE is nested in another CASE

```
CASE
    WHEN(
        xyz <> a
        AND abc <> 3
        AND
            CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(o.RepCode, 1)) = 1 THEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(o.RepCode, 1)) >= 5 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END
                ELSE 0
            END
    )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
```

I get the below error on the first CASE after the second AND before WHEN ISNUMERIC()

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing criteria in your outermost case statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN(
        xyz <> a
        AND abc <> 3
        AND
            CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(o.RepCode, 1)) = 1 THEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(o.RepCode, 1)) >= 5 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END
                ELSE 0
            END = ?  -- Missing criteria
    )  
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
```

**Edit:** Not sure there's an ideal way to format this, but I find the following to be easier to follow:

```
CASE WHEN (    xyz <> a      
           AND abc <> 3  
           AND CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(o.RepCode, 1)) = 1 
                    THEN CASE WHEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(o.RepCode, 1)) >= 5 
                              THEN 1
                              ELSE 0
                         END
                    ELSE 0
               END = ? -- Missing Criteria
           ) 
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: `outermost case statement` It's not the outer most. It's sorta in the middle

Comment: @ConradFrix I see it as the `WHEN` of the outermost case statement is missing a comparison.

Comment: What should the last END equal to? 0 or 1?

Comment: @user793468 if you want to be true when RepCode > 5 then 1

Comment: @GoatCO In the edited version, you have '= ?' after the parenthesis. I believe it should be inside the parenthesis after the END.